# "Natural" finite measure over continuous probability densities over the interval $[0,a]$

Tags: density-function, measure-theory

I wonder whether there is a "natural" finite measure $\mu$ (such as the Lebesgue-Measure on $\mathbb{R}\cap[0,a]$) over the space of all continous probability density functions on $[0,a]$.

EDIT: As my original question was apparently to vague, I wonder whether it helps if we presuppose that the measure $\mu$ is to be defined on the Borel sigma algebra $B(C_p([0,a],\mathbb{R}))$ where I denote all the continuous probability density functions on $[0,a]$ with $C_p([0,a],\mathbb{R})$

Comment: Yes, the empirical distribution of all the $[0,a]$ densities that appear in this world. But will we ever know this probability measure? Never.

Comment: This seems more relevant for the Mathematics community.

Comment: @MotiN Why? This is a very relevant _empirical_ research question. For example, if I wanted to estimate the model using [Bayesian statistics](http://www.stanfordphd.com/Bayesian_Statistics.html), I would have to think which prior I should put over the $[0,a]$ measures... I would not even say that the question pertains to _theoretical_ statistics. It is fairly applied.

Comment: You need to clarify what you might mean by "natural."  There definitely are finite measures, but how are we supposed to distinguish among them?  What is your definition of "natural"?

Comment: Asking him to specify what constitutes "natural" is tantamount to asking him to answer his own question - once you specify a definition of the scope of this concept, you have the scope of the allowable distributions.

Comment: If the Lebesgue-Measure is considered 'natural' (related to length, area, volume, etc.), then the metric induced by the inner product $<f,g> = \int_0^a f(t)g(t)dt$ seems like a logical/natural/whatever extension from Euclidean space to the space of continuous (probability density) functions on the domain $[0,a]$.

Comment: @Ben The point, as well illustrated by Martijn's example, is that he has introduced additional mathematical structure (a commutative topological group structure on the set of real numbers), and *with respect to this structure* the Lebesgue measure enjoys a special status.  What would be the special structure in this question?  There are so many possibilities that I cannot conceive of there being any unique sense of "natural:" it has to depend on some unstated assumptions.

Comment: @whuber: I understand the issues you raise, and they would make an excellent answer.  The thing with these questions is that the OP may not know enough preliminary material to frame exactly what he wants.  I find no problem with an OP asking if there is a "natural" such-and-such, and leaving it to experts to suggest what "natural" might mean.  The OP's profile says he is a bachelor student, so he might not yet be familiar with the main topological structures that are imposed on the real interval, or even with Lebesgue measure.  Both Martjin and your comments would serve as helpful answers.